# What is the significance of UTF-8?

Tags: html

More specifically, is UTF-8 in HTML used to store characters in binary and provide a wide range of use for other languages or does it function the same way as ASCII when you invoke the fromCharCode attribute? I'm having a hard time understanding it because I see people write utf-8 charset, but don't really understand its purpose unless it's used for saving characters into binary.

Comment: Is your Google broken? Search for *What is UTF-8*.

Comment: That is a bit snarky - just downvote the question.

Comment: If you have not already, that is.

Answer (score 0):

utf-8 is specified so that unicode characters will not show up as gibberish on certain browsers. It isn't always required, but highly suggested.